# JEP библиотека и BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Я использую стороннюю библиотеку `org.nfunk.jep`. Но все вычисления внутри этой библиотеки производятся в `double`, вне зависимости от того, какой тип имели входные переменные, так как метод `addVariable` в классе `JEP` может принимать на вход переменные только следующих типов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, когда я выполняю следующий код:

```
BigDecimal value1 = new BigDecimal("29250.24");
BigDecimal value2 = new BigDecimal("263.21");
JEP calc = new JEP();
calc.addVariable("var1", Double.parseDouble(value1));
calc.addVariable("var2", Double.parseDouble(value2));
calc.parseExpression("var1 - var2");
System.out.println("Результат: " + calc.getValue());
```

я хочу получить "28987.03", но в действительности вывод такой:

> Результат: 28987.0300000002

Может, кто-нибудь знает, как работать с этой библиотекой и `BigDecimal` или знает похожие библиотеки, которые работают с числами `BigDecimal` типа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите функцию которая будет выдавать число из вышеуказанного числа,так что будет 2 цифры после запятой.